# How do I unescape a unicode escaped string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping, python-3.4

I have a unicode escaped string:

```
> str = 'blah\\x2Ddude'
```

I want to convert this string into the unicode unescaped version `'blah-dude'`

How do I do this?

Comment: It is not html escape string. Try: `import html; html.escape('this <is> &escaped&')` and `html.unescape('this &lt;is&gt; &amp;escaped&amp;')`

Comment: Where does the string come from? Do you understand the difference between `'\\x2d'` and `'\x2d'`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Encode it to `bytes` (using whatever codec, utf-8 probably works) then decode it using `unicode-escape`:

```
s = 'blah\\x2Ddude'

s.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
Out[133]: 'blah-dude'
```

Comment: It's not necessary to call the `encode` function.  You can just `import codecs` and then call `codecs.decode(s, 'unicode-escape')`

Comment: Oh my god finally.