# python3 replacing double backslash with single backslash

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

I need to replace `\\` with `\` in python3 in a complex string. I know that this question had been asked several times, but most of the time for simple strings so that none of the (accepted) answers really works for complex strings.

This is also **different** from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186839/python-replace-with) where the problem could be solved with `.decode('unicode_escape')` which does not work for this problem. **See below**.

Assuming the string is:

```
my_str = '\\xa5\\xc0\\xe6aK\\xf9\\x80\\xb1\\xc8*\x01\x12$\\xfbp\x1e(4\\xd6{;Z\\x'
```

---

Straight forward approach would be:

```
my_str.replace('\\','\')
```

which leads to:

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

---

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673994/python-regex-to-replace-double-backslash-with-single-backslash) suggests using:

```
my_str.replace('\\\\','\\')
```

Which results in:

```
'\\xa5\\xc0\\xe6aK\\xf9\\x80\\xb1\\xc8*\x01\x12$\\xfbp\x1e(4\\xd6{;Z\\x'
```

So, there is no change.

---

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452956/remove-escape-character-from-string) suggests:

```
b = bytes(my_str, encoding='utf-8')
b.decode('unicode-escape')
```

But this doesn't work for such a complex string:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 49-50: truncated \xXX escape

---

Using decode (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752485/how-to-replace-a-double-backslash-with-a-single-backslash-in-python)) results in:

```
my_str.decode('unicode_escape')
```

> AttributeError: 'my_str' object has no attribute 'decode'

---

A combination of encoding and then decoding using `unicode_esacpe` returns a totally different string (probably due to using `utf-16`, but `utf-8` results in an error, see above. Also, e.g. `latin1` doesn't work):

```
my_str.encode('utf-16').decode('unicode_escape')
'ÿþ\\\x00x\x00a\x005\x00\\\x00x\x00c\x000\x00\\\x00x\x00e\x006\x00a\x00K\x00\\\x00x\x00f\x009\x00\\\x00x\x008\x000\x00\\\x00x\x00b\x001\x00\\\x00x\x00c\x008\x00*\x00\x01\x00\x12\x00$\x00\\\x00x\x00f\x00b\x00p\x00\x1e\x00(\x004\x00\\\x00x\x00d\x006\x00{\x00;\x00Z\x00\\\x00x\x00'
```

---

Comment: Does `your_text.replace('\\', '')` work? You don't actually have any double literal backslashes there...

Comment: Right, this works. As soon as I put '\' as second argument, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you don't really need to do this.  Often, people print out values and see the double-backslash, but that's just Python's way of unambigiously showing you that there is a single backslash in the string.  Can you say more about where this string came from, and why you want to change it?

Comment: @black Give us more details, we can help fix things properly.  Or join us in the #python IRC channel on Freenode, where we can have an actual discussion and get to the bottom of it.

Comment: "But this doesn't work for such a complex string:" The problem is that the string ends with a single backslash followed by a lowercase x. The described problem is to replace sequences of (backslash, lowercase x, two hex digits) with the corresponding escaped Unicode code point; but *what do you want to do* when the hex digits are missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a closer look at the string, they are all single slash.

```
In [26]: my_str[0]
Out[26]: '\\'

In [27]: my_str[1]
Out[27]: 'x'

In [28]: len(my_str[0])
Out[28]: 1
```

And `my_str.replace('\\','\')` won't work because the token here is `\'`, which escapes `'` and waits for the another closing `'`.
Use `my_str.replace('\\', '')` instead

---

Update: after few more days, I realize the following discussion may also be helpful. If the intension of a string with escape (`'\\x'` or `'\\u'`) are eventually hex/unicode literals, they can be decoded by `escape_decode`.

```
import codecs
print(len(b'\x32'), b'\x32')                # 1 hex literal, '\x32' == '2'
print(len(b'\\x32'), b'\\x32')              # 4 chars including escapes
print(codecs.escape_decode('\\x32', 'hex')) # chars->literal, 4->1

# 1 b'2'
# 4 b'\\x32'
# (b'2', 4)

s = '\\xa5\\xc0\\xe6aK\\xf9\\x80\\xb1\\xc8*\x01\x12$\\xfbp\x1e(4\\xd6{;Z'
ed, _ = codecs.escape_decode(s, 'hex')
print(len(s), s)
print(len(ed), ed)

# 49 \xa5\xc0\xe6aK\xf9\x80\xb1\xc8*$\xfbp(4\xd6{;Z
# 22 b'\xa5\xc0\xe6aK\xf9\x80\xb1\xc8*\x01\x12$\xfbp\x1e(4\xd6{;Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
s  = '\\xa5\\xc0\\xe6aK\\xf9\\x80\\xb1\\xc8*\x01\x12$\\xfbp\x1e(4\\xd6{;Z\\x'

s = s.replace('\\','\')

print(s)
```

you get

```
 File "main.py", line 3
    s = s.replace('\\','\')
                         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

because in `'\'` the \ escapes the `'` . Your string is left open.

You do not have any double \ in `s` - its just *displaying* it as such, do distinguish it from `\` used to escape stuff if you inspect it.

If you `print(s)` you get `\xa5\xc0\xe6aK\xf9\x80\xb1\xc8*$\xfbp(4\xd6{;Z\x`