# Decoding specific escaped characters in a Python string

Tags: python, escaping, ascii

I have a Python variable (named `var`) containing a string with the following literal data:

```
day\r\n\\night
```

in hex, it is:

```
64  61  79  5C  72  5C  6E  5C  5C  6E  69  67  68  74  07
d   a   y   \   r   \   n   \   \   n   i   g   h   t   BEL
```

I need to decode `\\`, `\r` and `\n` *only*.

The desired output (in hex):

```
64  61  79  0D  0A  5C  6E  69  67  68  74  07
d   a   y   CR  LF  \   n   i   g   h   t   BEL
```

Using `decode` doesn't work:

```
>>> print(var.decode('ascii'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?
```

Using regex to find and replace `\\`, `\r` and `\n` with their escaped values is unsuccessful, as the `\n` in `\night` is treated as a 0x0A.

Is it possible to specify which characters I want to `decode`, or is there a more appropriate module? I'm using Python 3.10.2.

Comment: Why would the output contain BEL if it isn't in the string?

Comment: @ArthurKing It's in the string, but it does not display properly on the website. The hex dump is to help show the contents of the string on any platform.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @ArthurKing I did, yes, thank you for posting, however my goal is to have the output not print the ASCII control code names but the bytes themselves, while also leaving all other ASCII control codes alone. I posted an answer which demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to everyone that contributed their answers, but none of them seemed to solve my issue completely. After long time of research I found [this solution from sahil Kothiya](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/43430/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220328052938/https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/43430/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)) -- I modified it to resolve my specific issue:

```
import re, codecs

ESCAPE_SEQUENCE_RE = re.compile(r'''
    ( \\[\\nr]  # Single-character escapes
    )''', re.UNICODE | re.VERBOSE)

def decode_escapes(s):
    def decode_match(match):
        return codecs.decode(match.group(0), 'unicode-escape')
return ESCAPE_SEQUENCE_RE.sub(decode_match, s)
```

---

Demonstration in IDLE:

[image: IDLE demo]

Special characters shown in Notepad++:

[image: NP++ demo]

Hex dump of output string:

[image: hexdump]

---

It even works with Unicode characters (an important component to my script).

Demonstration in IDLE:

[image: IDLE demo-2]

Special characters shown in Notepad++:

[image: NP++ demo-2]

Hex dump of output string:

[image: hexdump-2]

Answer (score 1):

Find similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40453203/11041312). According to this you can do following

```py
var = r"day\r\n\\night"

# This is what you got previously
var.encode('ascii').hex()
# '64 61 79 5c 72 5c 6e 5c 5c 6e 69 67 68 74'

# To get required output do this
bytes(var, encoding='ascii').decode('unicode-escape').encode('ascii').hex()
# '64 61 79 0d 0a 5c 6e 69 67 68 74'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `var` is a string like this:

`64617905C725C6E5C5C6E69676877407` (without spaces)

you should try:

```py
i = 0
escaped = {'72': '0D', '6E': '0A', '5C': '5C'}
while i < len(var):
   if var[i:i+2] == '5C':                # checks if the caracter is a '\'
      i += 2                             # if yes, goes to next character hex code in var
      var[i-2:i+2] = escaped[var[i:i+2]] # replaces the '5Cxx' by its escaped value
   i += 2
```

It will replace the `\r \n \\` by the characters corresponding (`CR LF \`).

I'll later add converters between `day\r\l\\night` and `64617905C725C6E5C5C6E696768774`.

**EDIT:** Converters are here!
The converted string is `r` each time.
It handles the results of `input()` but for hard-coded strings you'll have to enter:
`var = 'day\\r\\l\\\\night'`
so that the code will understand it as **'day', then '\', then 'r', then '\', then 'n', then '\', then '\', then 'night'** and not **'day', then CR, then LF, then '\', then 'night'**; so that upon
`print(var)`
there will be printed
`day\r\n\\night`
and not

```
day
\night
```

---

```py
# convert string to hex
r = ''
for c in var:
   t = hex(ord(c))[2:]
   if ord(c) < 16: t = '0' + t
   r += t
```

```py
# convert hex to string
r = ''
c = 0
while c < len(var):
   # transforms each hex code point into a decimal number
   # I kind of cheat using `eval`. But don't worry. Doesn't matter.
   # anyway, it then adds the corresponding character to `r`.
   r += eval('chr(0x' + var[c:c+2] + ')') # does like, `r += chr(0x5C)` for example.
   c += 2
```