# Read csv file containing escape characters in Python

Tags: python, csv, unicode

Hi and many thanks in advance!

I'm working on a Python script handling utf-8 strings and replacing specific characters. Therefore I use `msgText.replace(thePair[0], thePair[1])` while looping trough a list which defines unicode characters and their desired replacement, as shown below.

```
theList = [
    ('\U0001F601', '1f601.png'),
    ('\U0001F602', '1f602.png'), ...
]
```

Up to here everything works fine. But now consider a **csv file** which contains the characters to be replaced, as shown below.

```
\U0001F601;1f601.png
\U0001F602;1f602.png
...
```

I miserably failed in reading the csv data into the list due to the **escape characters**. I read the data using the `csv` module like this:

```
with open('Data.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as theCSV:
    theList=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(theCSV, delimiter=';')]
```

This results in pairs like `('\\U0001F601', '1f601.png')` which evade the escape characters (note the double backslash). I tried several methods of modifying the string or other methods of reading the csv data, but I was not able to solve my problem.
How could I accomplish my goal to read csv data into pairs which contain escape characters?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22601369/2896976

Comment: From the information you're giving, I am not sure why you'd want to go the detour via csv and not just find a generic function to turn any \U000XXXXX character into xxxxx.png ?

Comment: @trs Unfortunately the pattern is not always the same. (The csv data contains several hundreds of lines.)

Comment: @user2896976 I cannot figure out how to use `.encode().decode('unicode-escape')` for the list of tuples.

Comment: If your data is always just a pair you can do: `theList=[(line[0].encode().decode('unicode-escape'), line[1]) for line in csv.reader(theCSV, delimiter=';') if line]` Which will encode the first element. I also added an `if` in there to skip blank lines

Comment: @user2896976 Thanks a lot, works as desired!

Comment: The issue is that the CSV file shown here **does not** contain the characters to be replaced. It contains values that start with a backslash, uppercase U etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding the solution for reading csv data containing escape characters for the sake of completeness. Consider a file `Data.csv` defining the replacement pattern:

```
\U0001F601;1f601.png
\U0001F602;1f602.png
```

Short version (using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)):

```
import csv

# define replacement list (short version)
with open('Data.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvFile:
    replList=[(line[0].encode().decode('unicode-escape'), line[1]) \
        for line in csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=';') if line]
csvFile.close()
```

Prolonged version (probably easier to understand):

```
import csv

# define replacement list (step by step)
replList=[]
with open('Data.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvFile:
    for line in csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=';'):
        if line:  # skip blank lines
            replList.append((line[0].encode().decode('unicode-escape'), line[1]))
csvFile.close()
```