# Fix a unicode string broken by (some) escaped backslashes

Tags: python, string, unicode

I was looking at this question: [python3 replacing double backslash with single backslash [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199840/python3-replacing-double-backslash-with-single-backslash)

and sifting through the responses to similar questions: [Python Replace \ with \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186839/python-replace-with) , 
[Why can't Python's raw string literals end with a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash)
, [How do I unescape a unicode escaped string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601291/how-do-i-unescape-a-unicode-escaped-string-in-python)

When I realised that none of the answers really solve this problem.
Say I have a broken unicode string, it contains **both** escaped backslashes and escape characters:

```
my_str = '\\xa5\\xc0\\xe6aK\xf9\\x80\\xb1\\xc8*\x01\x12$\\xfbp\x1e(4\\xd6{;Z'
```

When I print it, some characters evaluate:

```
print(my_str)
\xa5\xc0\xe6aKù\x80\xb1\xc8*☺↕$\xfbp▲(4\xd6{;Z
```

I can manually fix it like this:

```
my_str = repr(my_str)
my_str
"'\\\\xa5\\\\xc0\\\\xe6aKù\\\\x80\\\\xb1\\\\xc8*\\x01\\x12$\\\\xfbp\\x1e(4\\\\xd6{;Z'"
my_str = my_str.replace('\\\\','\\')
print(my_str)
'\xa5\xc0\xe6aKù\x80\xb1\xc8*\x01\x12$\xfbp\x1e(4\xd6{;Z'
```

But at this point I have to manually copy and paste the result of print into a variable to finish the fix:

```
my_str = '\xa5\xc0\xe6aKù\x80\xb1\xc8*\x01\x12$\xfbp\x1e(4\xd6{;Z'
print(my_str)
¥ÀæaKù±È*☺↕$ûp▲(4Ö{;Z
```

How do I do this without copying and pasting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strip off the single quotes, encode to get bytes, then decode using "unicode-escape":

```
# original code
my_str = '\\xa5\\xc0\\xe6aK\xf9\\x80\\xb1\\xc8*\x01\x12$\\xfbp\x1e(4\\xd6{;Z'
my_str = repr(my_str)
my_str = my_str.replace('\\\\','\\')
print(my_str)
# encode/decode stuff
print(my_str.strip("'").encode().decode("unicode-escape"))
```

prints:

```
'\xa5\xc0\xe6aKù\x80\xb1\xc8*\x01\x12$\xfbp\x1e(4\xd6{;Z'
¥ÀæaKÃ¹±È*$ûp(4Ö{;Z
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.. I was wondering why it was different. I also found another answer that works (using `ast.literal_eval`) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886123/reverse-repr-function-in-python

Comment: `my_str.strip("'").encode().decode("unicode-escape")` throws me a `UnicodeDecodeError` though.

Comment: Ah, that would be because a ù snuck in there somehow.. happens in python 2.7. literal_eval works in 2.7 though.

Comment: it depends on your terminal too. I pasted OP output string. I shouldn't have done that :) I have edited to start from OP original input

Comment: ast.literal_eval gives a slightly different result

Comment: literal_eval gives a weird result (Ñ└µaK∙Ç▒╚*☺↕$√p▲(4╓{;Z) in 2.7, where encode/decode doesn't work. It still doesn't work when I set `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and literal_eval is still weird. The differences in 3 seem to be at the ù character that's causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I've mentioned [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) in the comments on the accepted answer. But feel I should include a code snippet here:

[Reverse repr function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886123/reverse-repr-function-in-python)

```
from ast import literal_eval

my_str = '\\xa5\\xc0\\xe6aK\xf9\\x80\\xb1\\xc8*\x01\x12$\\xfbp\x1e(4\\xd6{;Z'
my_str = repr(my_str)
my_str = my_str.replace('\\\\','\\')
print(literal_eval(my_str))
```

Result (Python 3):

```
¥ÀæaKù±È*☺↕$ûp▲(4Ö{;Z
```